# JSF RichFaces reRender event changes rich:dataGrid structure

Tags: datagrid, jboss, richfaces, seam, ajax4jsf

I am looking for a hint on how to handle a strange effect on rerendering a datagrid. I have the following grid structure:

```
<rich:dataGrid id="allProductsGrid" value="#{allProducts}" var="_product">                       
     <s:div styleClass="grid-element">
         <s:link view="/product.xhtml">
             <s:div styleClass="product-element">                                                                                                           
                 <h:graphicImage value="/content/images?id=#{_product.image.id}&amp;width=170"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
             </s:div>                           
             <div id="title">
                 <h:outputText value="#{_product.name}" />
             </div>
             <f:param name="productId" value="#{_product.id}" />
        </s:link>                                                                
     </s:div>
 </rich:dataGrid>
```

The grid gets reRendered on a onkeyup-event fired by an search input field. No magic so far. Now the problem is that the reRendering changes the structure of the html produced (DOM). As a result the links are not working anymore.

The firebug-html-inspect on the first rendering of the page is as follows:

```
 <div id="j_id86:allProductsGrid:0:j_id124" class="grid-element">
    <a id=".. " onclick=".." href="/portal/product.vc?productId=22&cid=69">
        <div id="j_id86:allProductsGrid:0:j_id126" class="product-element">
            <img src="/portal/content/images?id=&width=170">
        </div>
        <div id="title">Sample Product</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

After reRendering the grid the html output is that:

```
<div id="j_id86:allProductsGrid:0:j_id124" class="grid-element">
    <a id=".." onclick=".." href="/portal/product.vc?productId=22&cid=76"></a>
    <div id="j_id86:allProductsGrid:0:j_id126" class="product-element">
        <img src="/portal/content/images?id=&width=170">
    </div>
    <div id="title">Sample Product</div>
</div>
```

The result is that the a-tag is not wrapping the product-element anymore. Can anybody give me a hint on what might be wrong here?? 
Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

josh

ps: using Seam 2.2.2 / JSF Mojarra 2.0.3 / RichFaces 3.3.3

Comment: really no one facing that effect?

Comment: Have you tried changing the scope of your bean? It looks like seam though of that ajax request as a new request, that's why the cid is different.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `allProducts` bean has ViewScope instead of RequestScope. So in rerender the data will persist in the call.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The responsable action bean is in ScopeType.PAGE - but actually I don't think this problem is a scope problem, isn't it? - since the grid data (i.e. the products) is refreshing correctly.